# How to verify that placeholder text disappears on entering some text in a search box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where I have to verify two things:
a) placeholder text
b) placeholder text disappears on entering some text.

I am done with scenario 1 using getAttribute("placeholder");

For scenario b) I am stuck as even after entering text, placeholder value remains the same.
I even tried getText(), but it shows null value in both cases.

So is there some other way??

**EDIT: HTML**
Before entering text:

```
<div class="pull-left"> <div class="form-group"> <input id="edit-search-block-form" class="form-control" type="text" name="keys" placeholder="How can we help you?"/>
```

It remains the same

```
</div> <button class="btn btn-primary" name="op" type="submit">Search</button> </div>
```

After entering text

```
<div class="pull-left"> <div class="form-group"> <input id="edit-search-block-form" class="form-control" type="text" name="keys" placeholder="How can we help you?"/> </div> <button class="btn btn-primary" name="op" type="submit">Search</button> </div>
```

Comment: Can you please point out to the page? Or paste here html content before and after entering text in placeholder.

Comment: Before entering text:  <div class="pull-left">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="edit-search-block-form" class="form-control" type="text" name="keys" placeholder="How can we help you?"/>

It remains the same
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="op" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
After entering text
<div class="pull-left">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="edit-search-block-form" class="form-control" type="text" name="keys" placeholder="How can we help you?"/>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="op" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>

Comment: hm, there is no change in element before and after entering element. I also tried.

Comment: I believe that the placeholder="How can we help you?" will remain the same in the HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the attribute of input tag, 'placeholder' and all other attributes will remain the same in the HTML code even after entering text in the input field. How do you expect the HTML code to change dynamically, unless you are have an AJAX call or your are reloading the page after doing a form submit.

"value" attribute is the one that changes(though it wont be reflected in the HTML code). I think getText is returning blank because it does'nt know how to handle the attribute placeholder

Try the following code :-

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("edit-search-block-form"));

System.out.println("placeholder-before : " + input.getAttribute("placeholder"));
System.out.println("value-before : " + input.getAttribute("value"));

input.sendKeys("New text goes here");

System.out.println("placeholder-after : " + input.getAttribute("placeholder"));
System.out.println("value-after : " + input.getAttribute("value"));
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: It's fail using this approach. input.getAttribute("placeholder") will yield placeholder attribute, while input.getAttribute('value') will yield empty string at the first and actual value after send key.
I've already test using google chrome browser via developer tools and C# using selenium.